# reading paritionned dataset in aws s3 with pyarrow doesn't add partition columns

Tags: pandas, amazon-s3, parquet, pyarrow

i'm trying to read a partitionned dataset in aws s3, it looks like :

```
MyDirectory--code=1--file.parquet
           --code=2--another.parquet
           --code=3--another.parquet
```

i created a file_list containing the path to all the files in the directory then executed

```
df = pq.ParquetDataset(file_list, filesystem=fs).read().to_pandas()
```

everything works except that the partition column code doesn't exist in the dataframe df.
i tried it also using one path  to MyDirectory insted of file_list, but found an error 
"Found files in an intermediate directory: s3://bucket/Mydirectoty", i can't find any answer online.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

AWS has a project ([AWS Data Wrangler](https://github.com/awslabs/aws-data-wrangler)) that helps with the integration between Pandas/PyArrow and their services.

This snippet should work:

```
import awswrangler as wr

# Write
wr.s3.to_parquet(
    df=df,
    path="s3://...",
    mode="overwrite",
    dataset=True,
    database="my_databse",  # Optional, only if you want it available on Athena/Glue Catalog
    table="my_table",
    partition_cols=["PARTITION_COL_NAME"])

# READ
df = wr.s3.read_parquet(path="s3://...", dataset=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're happy with other tools you can give `dask` a try. Assume all the data you want to read is in `s3://folder` you can just use

```py
import dask.dataframe as dd
storage_options = {
            'key': your_key,
            'secret': your_secret}
df = dd.read_parquet("s3://folder",
                     storage_options=storage_options)
```

Comment: i tested that byt dd.read_parquet read single parquet files, and can not read a partitionned data set,